# how to set a size for a QFileDialog in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I'm trying to implement a file browser in a QT application. All works well using the following line of code.

```
QString file_name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a file", QDir::homePath(), "JSON File (*.json)");
```

Now, I'm trying to run this in a laptop with a 4K display, so I enable the HDPI using the following line of code:

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

Everything looks good, but when I open the QT App in a 1080p monitor and click on the button to show the file browser, the window is too big . If the QT app is opened in a 4K monitor all is perfect and looks good.

[image]

the same happens when I drag the window from a 4k monitor to a 1080p monitor. In the 4K monitor looks good, but when I drag to the 1080p monitor the window gets too big.

I'm using Windows 10 and QT 5.15.10.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: `QFileDialog` just opens your file manager and it gets all properties from your system which means that in `1080p monitor` open one file manager window without Running your Qt app and see if is there any difference between this and when you open it from your qt app or not.

Comment: for adjustable size file selection dialogue you have to look some custome implimentation of it or make your own file selection Dialog. Existing one it purely OS dependant.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R  The only solution I found is using the `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` flag in `QFileDialog` ->  `QString file_name = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a file", QDir::homePath(), "JSON File (*.json)");, QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);`. It will use a QT style. I don't like how it looks (it looks older) but it has a better behavior when moving the dialog window between monitors with different resolution, the aspect ratios are kept. Did you find any other solution?

Comment: @BadRobot  I test what you say and yeah it works but it is too old. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCCxD.png , But  I noticed that this didn't happen for the Qt creator file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I check the Source code of [qt-creator](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator) and from [this](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/commit/35de9566b6b83d9ac42903fb1fabb0b4dca3f5f0) commit I noticed that they didn't use **QFileDialog !**

> Changes the MainWindow to use FileUtils::getFilePaths function to
> access files on devices instead of QFileDialog.

I understand that they create their own class and call it [fileutils](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/e2706436a902ea069ca537dde50a0ce0533d7ccc/src/libs/utils/fileutils.cpp)

I test and reduced my resolution and I noticed that it works well.

As you mentioned in the comment instead of `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog)` you can also add

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontUseNativeDialogs);
```

in `main.cpp`.

From [QFileDialog doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html)

> `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` is not supported on **macOS** when
> using the native file dialog.